# Как запретить считывание html в тексте

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Нужно запретить читать html код в определённом теге

и всё что внитри него заставить воспринимать как текст даже если внутри будут html теги. То есть если от сервера придёт < br > Привет то не нужно делать перенос строки а просто вывесли тег как текст. Вро де бы как в html есть специальные теги текст в которых всегда текст

Не нашёл ответа в гугле

Comment: Вы это только средствами html и css хотите сделать?

Comment: Не обязательно, но желательно

Comment: есть тег  `<plaintext>` - он делает то что вам нужно, но у него есть минус: у него нет "стопа". Он работает от начало объявления, и до конца документа

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тег `script` стандартный, и работает во всех браузерах...
Он не только для кода. Фактически, в этом теге может быть любое текстовое содержимое.
Главное указать MIME-тип, чтобы браузер не воспринимал содержимое как код:

```js
document.querySelector('#show').addEventListener('click', e => {
  const hc = document.querySelector('#hidden-content'); 
  e.target.parentElement.textContent = hc.innerHTML; // ◀
});
```

```css
div { white-space: pre-line; }
```

```html
<p>Видим на странице</p>
<div>
  <button id="show">Показать скрытое как текст</button>
</div>

<!-- Невидимый контент -->
<script type="text/html" id="hidden-content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</script>
```

Единственное что нельзя помещать в такой элемент - это вложенные `script` (из-за закрывающего тега).

Answer (score 3):

```html
<xmp>
  <h1>asdasd</h1>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
</xmp>
```

Answer (score 3):

Обратите внимание на тег `<pre>`. Но у него есть некоторый ограничения на использование следующих тегов `<big>, <img>, <object>, <small>, <sub>, <sup>`.

Comment: `<pre>` всё же обрабатывает некоторые теги. Во всяком случае `<p>` и `<br>` точно

Answer (score 1):

Если использовать только html, то только при использовании тега `<plaintext>` код будет выводиться как есть без его применения. Однако тег не входит в спецификацию. Верстка станет невалидной.

```
<plaintext>Этот тег<br>выведется как есть</plaintext>
```

Код лучше предварительно обработать на сервере при помощи функций, которые вернут текст с сущностями, тогда всё будет как надо. Например, в PHP:

```
echo htmlentities("Этот тег<br>выведется как есть", ENT_QUOTES);
```

Comment: Тег <plaintext> действует до конца кода веб-страницы, включая закрывающие теги </body> и </html>." Я о нем написал в коментах, но мне кажется это не то, что нужно автору...я затестил, у меня и скрипты тоже выводятся...как то криво работает этот тег

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Лучше вообще не использовать такие теги. Их с большой вероятностью выпилят в будущем.